# Is ABA relevant for push/insertion operations when using the CAS idiom?

Tags: multithreading, language-agnostic, compare-and-swap, aba

The following pseudo-code is taken from http://15418.courses.cs.cmu.edu/spring2013/article/46

```
while (1) {
  n->next = p->next;
  Node *old_next = p->next;
  if (compare_and_swap(&p->next, old_next, n) == old_next)
    return;
}
```

This is the `push` operation for a lock-free stack that uses the compare and swap idiom, but does it atomically. It does not seem an ABA issue is relevant here, and I am wondering if that's generally the case for push and insertion operations?

Answer (score 1):

You are right that this function does not suffer from the ABA problem, because there is nothing that depends on the `old_next` value before the call to `compare_and_swap`.

Consider the (simplified) pop operation:

```
  while (1) {
    Node *top = s->top;
    if (top == NULL)
      return NULL;
    Node *new_top = top->next;
    if (compare_and_swap(&s->top, top, new_top);
      return top;
  }
}
```

Here we load `s->top` into `top` and later perform a CAS on `s->top` with `top` as expected value. But before the CAS, we read `top->next`, so we perform an operation that depends on `top`! This is what causes the ABA problem.

It is not possible to generally state that all push/insert operations are free of the ABA problem, since it depends on more details. As a somewhat contrived example, consider a push operation that conditionally pushes the value only if it is greater.

```
while (1) {
  n->next = p->next;
  Node *old_next = p->next;
  if (n->value < old_next->value)
    return;
  if (compare_and_swap(&p->next, old_next, n) == old_next)
    return;
}
```

This also suffers from the ABA problem, because it might break our invariant that the values are strictly ordered.

Answer (score 0):

There is no ABA issue with this code, but that's really because it doesn't do very much.

The problem is fundamentally that you use `compare_and_swap(&p->next, old_next, n)` to make sure that the stack hasn't changed since you last looked at it, but it does *not* reliably do that.

Between the time you read `n->next` and the time you do the `compare_and_swap`, other threads could have:

1. Popped `n->next`
2. Pushed a bunch of other stuff
3. Re-pushed the old `n->next`

Then your `compare_and_swap` would succeed even though the stack has changed.

This is not a problem for you, because you never look at any of the fields of `n->next`.  It doesn't matter that the stack has changed, because all you care about is the `n->next` pointer.

If you *did* have to look inside that object, though, then your code would be broken.  For instance, if you added a `stack_size` field to atomically keep track of the stack size, then you'd set `n->stack_size = old_next->stack_size+1`, and this would be *wrong* if the stack had changed as above.

So it is *not* true in general that insert operations are ABA-proof.